# EXCEL: How do I ignore several header rows while looping through columns to change number format?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below is working.  It will progress through all columns in the sheet and change the data within it to a number of fixed length based on the number found in the 2nd row.

My issue is that it selects the entire column when doing so.  This is a problem for me since I have 4 header rows that I do not want converted.

My first thought was to offset/resize a selection and apply changes to all cells, but I'm simply having no luck doing that.

Can anyone modify this code to ignore the first 4 header rows as it progresses through the columns?

Note:  lastCol is a separate function that simply returns an integer value with the number of the last used column on the sheet.

```
Sub FormatFixedNumber()

    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To lastCol 'replace 10 by the index of the last column of your spreadsheet
        With Columns(i)
            .NumberFormat = String(.Cells(2, 1), "0") 'number length is in second row
        End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.  I added a Constant to hold the header rows count.

EDIT: Added code to just go to last row as requested.  Also checks that LastRow is greater than HEADER_ROWS.  And fixed some convoluted adding and subtracting of the HEADER_ROWS in the Resize/Offset.

```
Sub FormatFixedNumber()
Const HEADER_ROWS As Long = 4
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To LastCol    'replace 10 by the index of the last column of your spreadsheet
    With Columns(i)
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow > HEADER_ROWS Then
            With .Resize(LastRow - HEADER_ROWS).Offset(HEADER_ROWS)
                .NumberFormat = String(.EntireColumn.Cells(2, 1), "0")    'number length is in second row
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly except that it selects the entire column.  Is it possible to modify this to simply go to the last row?  I was trying out UsedRange.Rows, but having no luck.

Comment: woops found a typo - the old Row not Rows.  Should have been End(xlup).Row.  Fixed now.